# visibility of accounts and activities across business units

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In the CRM installation of a customer of ours, we face some peculiarities. First off, an organisational chart illustrating the structure of the business units:

[organisational chart http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/9153/orgchart.jpg](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/9153/orgchart.jpg)

When Alice or Bob create an account (or an activity or a contact) for (or: owned by) Paul, George or Ringo, then John can't see those entities. Setting the acces level to "*parent: child business units*" for John solves the problem, but then John can also see the activities of Alice and Bob and this isn't what our client wants.

On the other hand, I have examples that seem contradictory to eachother and to the above: an account created by Ringo and owned by Paul that is visible to John, and an account created by George and owned by George, which is **not** visible to John.

**The main question is**: is John ever able to see entities that are created by/for an owned by persons in the underlying business units (sales reps 1/2/3)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  assumption here is that Alice and Bob is a parent of John's BU, and in hand John is in the Parent Business unit of the 3 BU below.

John's role will need to be modified to include those entities and reflect 3/4 pie access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that customer isn't a customer anymore, so I can't check it.
One thing though: 3/4 pie acces means "parent: child business units" and as I already mentioned in my original question, this did solve the problem, but then John could also see the entities of Alice and Bob and this is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Bart the 3/4 pie is the answer here, but if the users placed in the top business unit assign a task to one of the sales reps; the activity is inadvertedly being moved to the sales rep business unit rather than staying in the mangement business unit. Which is why John can see these activities. The "Created By" does not apply any security measures, the record ownership does imply the business unit however. To solve this you could use teams rather than business units to segregate the data and assign team ownership and adding John to only the teams where he should have access to the records. Teams can work around and transcend business units and they can add additional roles to users granting additional access. Note that CRM's security role model is permissive rather than restrictive meaning that having two roles (of which one could be assigned through team membership) will always give users more permissions and will never decrease the permissions. So adding teams in the lower sales rep BU's and assigning the records to those will also move the records to those lower BU's still allowing John to see them (if ofcourse John has the 3/4 permissions).

Hope this helps,

Alex